# ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_1' (type Sequential)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm new to TensorFlow and I'm attempting to build a very simple model. However, I keep encountering an error, which I believe might be related to the input shape. I understand that the input shape should match the feature vector, but for some reason, it's not working, and I'm getting this error:

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_1' (type Sequential).

```
Input 0 of layer "flatten_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=1, found ndim=0. Full shape received: ()
```

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
arr1 =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
arr2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
arr3 = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]
arr4 = [14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24 ]
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((arr1, arr2))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((arr3, arr4))


BATCH_SIZE = 2
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 2

train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE)
test_dataset = test_dataset

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1,1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])



model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10)
```

I tried with different input shape. but it did not work.

Comment: you need to batch your dataset `.batch(4)` and your input shape is `(1,)`